# Power Automate: populate word document. Images?

Tags: sharepoint, cpu-word, powerapps, power-automate

I'm working for a flow to populate a word document. I have a table with multiple items filled in, but I would like also to add attachments from sharepoint based on ID. The problem is that I could have multiple images for every item so I don't know how this could be solved..
Thank you for reading.
Have a good day!

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to handle this is quite complex. If you have a Microsoft Word template with say, 4 image *placeholders*, you will need to plug in 4 images every time or the `Populate Word Template` action in Flow will fail.

**Try this: (from memory)**

- **In the Sharepoint site:**
- Place a `defaultImage.jpg` file in the `Site Assets` folder

  - This will be the default image placed into the template when the # of Attachments <> the number of placeholder images.
- **In Flow:**
- `Initialize Variable` (`varPhotoArray`, Array)
- `Initialize Variable` (`varCounter`, Number)
- `Get Attachments`
- `Apply to each` Attachment

  - `Increment Variable` `varCounter` by 1
  - `Append to Array Variable` `varPhotoArray`
  - This will place the 0 to 4 attachments that may be present in Sharepoint into an array variable
- Create a new `Do until` action outside the `Apply to each` loop

  - Do until `varCounter is equal to 4` (or what ever the max photos is in the Word Template)
  - `Get file content by path` and grab the `defaultImage.jpg` file from `Site Assets`
  - `Increment Variable` `varCounter` by 1
  - This will "pad" the image array with the `defaultImage.jpg` until the number of images = the number of placeholder images in the template
- From here, you need to access positions within `varPhotoArray` and place them into the template
- I can't remember the exact syntax for this, but its something to the effect of `variables('varPhotoArray')[0]`, `variables('varPhotoArray')[1]`, `variables('varPhotoArray')[2]`, etc where the numeric value is the image's position within the array.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort and time, at last I opted for a different method because this **** is getting too hard.

Answer (score 1):

When you get attachment from an sharepoint list item, you hava an array, then you pass this array to the populate MS template step.
[Populate MS template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5tNs.png)

clicking this icon you change to receive an array of items.
[Populate MS template items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I9Vd6.png)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is giving me hope, but now the problem is that I get the files from the attachments and I read that the action "Populate word template" wants binary content for images. I have only the AbsoluteUri so I'm trying to find a way to convert it.

Comment: Try the `dataUriToBinary()` [WDL expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#dataUriToBinary)?

Comment: @marianr99 I think you must to use Get Attachment Content step and later put the result in populate word doc field.